# Neater way to find and display image file from ZIP archive with PHP

Tags: php, image, zip

```
function showimage($zip_file, $file_name) {
    if (file_exists($zip_file)) {
        $zip = zip_open($zip_file);
        while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
            if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
                if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) == $file_name) {
                    $theimg = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
                    $theimg = imagecreatefromstring($theimg);
                    if ($theimg !== false) {
                        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                        imagejpeg($theimg);
                        imagedestroy($theimg);
                    }
                    else { echo "Could not create image."; }
                    zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
                }
            }
            else { echo "Could not open."; }
        }
        zip_close($zip);
    }
    else { echo "File not found."; }
}
```

I'm running this function to open a specified zip file and then looping through the contents to find the specified file name, then creating an image from that file without the need to extract. I was just kind of curious how system intensive this process was, and if there was a neater/more direct manner of finding a file within a zip archive without the need to loop through and see if the name matches the given file name. Is there anyway to call a file directly from the zip file with the given name, assuming it exists?

The above code works... I guess I'm just trying to see how to do it better. If that makes sense.

Comment: Why are you reading the image with GD?  Why not just output the file contents?

Comment: GD would have been the only way from string  excepts he writes it to a local file @Brad

Comment: I wanted to avoid either extracting or creating new files, so used the GD functions to create the image from the raw data of the image file within the zip archive. Not the best way, but how I want it to work.

Comment: There is no reason to write it to a local file.  Just `echo ($theimg)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ZipArchive has a method for getting the file without actually searching for it.

```
function showimage($zip_file, $file_name) {
    $z = new ZipArchive();
    if ($z->open($zip_file) !== true) {
        echo "File not found.";
        return false;
    }

    $stat = $z->statName($file_name);
    $fp   = $z->getStream($file_name);
    if(!$fp) {
        echo "Could not load image.";
        return false;
    }

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $stat['size']);
    fpassthru($fp);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hadn't even looked at that class. Thank you for the info, should make things much easier. Also, thanks Stefan. I was under the impression I needed to create the image from the string returned from zip_entry_read(). I appreciate the responses, guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of using the GD Library neither writing to a file or anything else, as Brad said above. Just echo the result of the zip_entry_read() function and set the Content-Type. You could use something like this:

```
    function showimage($zip_file, $file_name) {
        if (file_exists($zip_file)) {
            $zip = zip_open($zip_file);
            while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
                if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
                    if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) == $file_name) {
                        $theimg = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
                        if ($theimg !== null) {
                            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                            echo $theimg;
                        }
                        else { echo "Could not load image."; }
                        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
                    }
                }
                else { echo "Could not open."; }
            }
            zip_close($zip);
        }
        else { echo "File not found."; }
    }
```

I think just not loading the GD library should improve the performance pretty good.